# Cancelling all notStarted or inProgress tasks if job is cancelled

Tags: azure-devops

I have a pipeline in AzureDevOps. It install several NPM dependencies and afterwards I use npm run <script_name>.
However if I cancel the job it still spawns webdrivers and it can be seen that the job is still running based on the counter.

Is there a way to cancel the tasks which are inProgress/notStarted if I cancel an ongoing job?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to cancel the tasks which are inProgress/notStarted if I cancel an ongoing job?

This needs to be explained in a case-by-case basis.

One case is that the task has not started yet after you choose to cancel the job. In this case, the task will not start.

Another case is that the task is inProgress when you cancel the job. This situation depends on the specific circumstances of your task running.

If your task just runs its own task, it can be canceled.

But if your task executes the task by calling other programs through the command,like using command line task invoke `MSBuild.exe` to build the project, there is no way to cancel the task after the command is issued. Even if you cancel the job, the task is still executed in the background until the job is completely closed.

Comment: So in general if I am using npm run which starts the test, there is no chance on cancelling the tests from continuing running if I cancel the job?

Comment: @vPilu, No, after canceling the job, the entire pipeline will have a cancellation process. The task will not be closed until the agent is closed. After the agent is recycled, the task will be closed.